# Reference a cell value as the Sheet name in a Match formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, syntax-error

I want to match the value in cell `A2` of my sheet to a header value on a different sheet and post back the matched column

I have a dropdown of sheet names in cell `F5` on a sheet called Filter_Maker

I need to reference this cell value as the sheet name in a match formula to the cell value in `A2`

I am trying

```
=MATCH($A2,indirect("'"Filter_Maker!F5"'!$A1:$H1"),0)
```

I am getting Formula parse error

Thanks for any assistance on this

Answer (score 0):

I got it. For anyone looking for this

where

`indirect(Filter_Maker!F5&"!$A2:$Z")`

references the data range. And

`SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A2,indirect(Filter_Maker!F5&"!$A1:$H1"),0),4),1,"")`

Selects the column to postback

```
=query(indirect(Filter_Maker!F5&"!$A2:$Z"),
  "Select "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH($A2,indirect(Filter_Maker!F5&"!$A1:$H1"),0),4),1,"")
  ,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(INDIRECT(Filter_Maker!F5&"A2:Z"); MATCH(A2; 
        INDIRECT(Filter_Maker!F5&"A2:Z1"); ))
```